# Classe de item na lista sempre inicializa ativo

Tags: html, ajax, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Utilizei como referência para a resolução do problema: [angular ng-repeat skip an item if it matches expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783816/angular-ng-repeat-skip-an-item-if-it-matches-expression).

Seguinte, sabemos que no Bootstrap tem a classe `active` para marcar com uma cor diferente dos elementos que não estão ativos e estou utilizando isso junto com o AngularJS para quando o usuário abrir a página e carregar com AJAX determinadas informações em um menu no lado esquerdo da tela.

Utilizo a directiva `ng-if` para verificar se o item não é o primeiro da lista e colocar a classe `active` nele, porém não esta funcionando, esta marcando `active` em todos os itens da lista.

Quero que o `Objeto 2`, por exemplo, fique branco ao fundo e sem a classe `active`.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" ng-init="inicializador()">
            <li ng-repeat="objeto in invoice.objetos" ng-if="objeto.posicao == 0" role="presentation" class="active">
                <a href="#">{{ objeto.atributo }}</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="objeto in invoice.objetos" ng-if="objeto.posicao != 0" role="presentation">
                <a href="#">{{ objeto.atributo }}</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$scope.inicializador = function() {

                    $http({
                        method : "GET",
                        url : '<c:url value="/cadastros/objeto/listObjetos" />'
                    }).then(function mySucces(response) {

                        var length = response.data.length;
                        var data = response.data;

                        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                            $scope.invoice.objetos.push({
                                posicao : i,
                                nome : data[i]
                            });
                        }

                    }, function myError(response) {
                        alert("Erro ao listar objetos");
                    });

                }
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Arrumei de uma maneira simples, utilizando a directiva `ng-class`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" ng-init="inicializadorObjeto()">
    <li ng-class="{'active':objeto.posicao == 0}" ng-repeat="objeto in invoice.objeto" role="presentation">
        <a href="#">{{ objeto.atributo }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Espero que na hora de selecionar outro objeto seja simples também, mas esse problema foi solucionado inicialmente.